# Android CheckBox and Row-OnClickListener

Tags: android, checkbox, listener

Adding a CheckBox to a listView-row deactivates the onClickListener of the row itself! I want to have rows where you can click on the row itself and select the checkbox too. How to do that?

//Row-Listener in the main-activity

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           //Does not get called
     }
});
```

//Checkbox-listener in the adapter

```
  final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) customView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                checked.set(position, checkBox.isChecked());
            }
        });
```

//Row-Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/custom_margin_left_and_right"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/custom_margin_left_and_right"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/custom_margin_left_and_right"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/custom_margin_left_and_right">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameTv"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/unbenannt"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these two properties to checkbox in xml :

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Example :

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="CheckBox" />
```

Comment: what is the second one for?

Answer (score 1):

Add

android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/custom_margin_left_and_right"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/custom_margin_left_and_right"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/custom_margin_left_and_right"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/custom_margin_left_and_right">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameTv"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/unbenannt"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:focusable="false" 
        android:clickable="true"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"/>
```

You need to set your checkbox focusable to false. then you will start getting individual click of inside row of listview. In your case checkbox is getting focus so it prevents click on your listview row. This should work if not feel free to comment on my question.